# VBA to insert in a cell in a column a formula to calculate when multiple IF AND conditions are met

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, excel-formula, nested-loops

I am stuck on writing a VBA code that will enable me to insert the following formula in column V (starts in V2 to last row since it is a dynamic range) If 3 AND conditions are met in other columns of the same sheet. I tried using a macro and inserting the formulaR1C1 it is asking but it gives me a syntax error.Also, I rather use a VBA code since it will be run on a very large database which has multiple sheets and the ranges will vary time by time. However, all formatting, header names and column numbers will always remain the same.

So my conditions are:

IF cell in Column M has a value, AND column N is NOT equal to 5, AND Column T is EMPTY then insert this formula in column V of that row:

Column G * (0.19) Also if same conditions are met, insert this formula in column X:

column V/ column Y As well as this formula in column O:

column M/ Column X If any of the 3 conditions are not met, then don't do anything and move to next row and resume

Do this for every row in sheet "CABC" and sheet "CXYZ" (number of row changes with every worksheet hence I need a Last row count included) Also, Sometimes in a new workbook one or both of these sheets will not be there so I need an error handler to move on in case it doesn't find the sheet.

I would give my code, however I really have non since none of the codes I found here or on youtube worked for me :(

This is the IF AND formula that is working for me for column V however when I insert it in VBA it doesn't work (doesn't work as .range.formula or as .range.formulaR1C1 from recorded macro)
formula:

```
"=IF(AND(M2>0,NOT(N2=5),T2=""),(G2*(0.07/(1+(0.05+0.07)))),"")"
```

Thank you so much!!

Comment: You need to double up the quotes in VBA.

Comment: `column M/ Column X `  formula : Which column is the formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with large amounts of data, using formulas to maintain speed slows down. It is good to use data as values. Please note that the contents below are replaced with values if there is any formulas applied. This applies only to column v, so the rest of the column is unclear, so please apply.

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB As Variant, rngDB As Range
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set Ws = Sheets(1) '<~~ set your sheet name ; Sheets("CABC")

    Set rngDB = Ws.UsedRange
    vDB = rngDB

    For i = 2 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        'This apply to V column
        If vDB(i, 13) > 0 And vDB(i, 14) <> 5 And vDB(i, 20) = "" Then
            'vDB(i,22) is V Column
            vDB(i, 22) = vDB(i, 7) * (0.07 / (1 + (0.05 + 0.07)))
        Else
            vDB(i, 22) = ""
        End If
    Next i
    rngDB = vDB

End Sub
```

### Sheet image

[image]

This is the added code.

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB As Variant, rngDB As Range
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set Ws = Sheets(1) '<~~ set your sheet name ; Sheets("CABC")

    Set rngDB = Ws.UsedRange
    vDB = rngDB

    For i = 2 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        'This apply to V column
        If vDB(i, 13) > 0 And vDB(i, 14) <> 5 And vDB(i, 20) = "" Then
            'vDB(i,22) is V Column
            vDB(i, 22) = vDB(i, 7) * (0.07 / (1 + (0.05 + 0.07)))  'column V
            vDB(i, 24) = vDB(i, 7) * 0.19                          'column X
            vDB(i, 15) = vDB(i, 22) / vDB(i, 24)                   'column O

        Else
            vDB(i, 22) = ""
        End If
    Next i
    rngDB = vDB

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked perfectly! Would you mind also telling me how could I adjust the formula so it returns an Absolute value? Thank you!

Comment: @ZepiQuinto, I edited answer.  But, I didn't fully understand your problem.